# Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'error' in null

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'error' in null
```

I dont know why this error appears. It occures on `'error' in json`

```
function parse(data, cb) {
    try {
        var json = $.parseJSON(data);
        if ('error' in json) {
            error(json.error);
            return;
        }
        cb(json);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
        error();
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `$.parseJSON()` is returning null. If you're trying to convert a json string into an object, use `JSON.parse()` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 1):

Your `data` is an empty `string`, `null`, or `undefined` and so the `json` variable is `NULL` because of incorrect behavior of `jQuery`:

> Prior to jQuery 1.9, $.parseJSON returned null instead of throwing an
>   error if it was passed an empty string, null, or undefined, even
>   though those are not valid JSON.

In later versions of `jQuery`, your `catch` block should catch the exception, which is a correct behavior. Don't use `$.parseJSON(data)` with that version of `jQuery`, use native method:

```
JSON.parse(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're fetching JSON, use $.getJSON() so it automatically converts the JSON to a JS Object.

Comment: Or you can use JSON.parse(data);

Answer (score 0):

from the jQuery documentation:

> Prior to **jQuery 1.9**, `$.parseJSON` returned null instead of throwing an error if it was passed an empty string, null, or undefined, even though those are not valid JSON.
>
> As of **jQuery 3.0**, `$.parseJSON` is deprecated. To parse JSON objects, use the native `JSON.parse` method instead.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

You can use the native JSON.parse and catch any problems if necessary (so you can show errors to the user):

```
try {
  var json = JSON.parse(data);

  // you know the json was parsed successfully
  //if you moved passed this line and didn't move
  //the the catch block :-)

  cb(json);

} catch (error) {

  error(json.error);
  return;

}
```

your `try & catch` blocks should catch any error thrown from the lines inside the `try` block. therefore, if `JSON,parse` won't succeed in converting the string to a JSON, it will throw an error, which will make this function break the `try` block and move to the `catch` block.

so, you can remove the `if` you added to check for errors and just use the `try & catch` you already have in your code